# numpy insert & append

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
X   ndarray   180x360
```

The following does not work

```
X = numpy.append(X, X[:,0], 1)
```

because `X[:,0]` has the wrong dimensions.

Is not this weird?

This way around the problem seems a bit dirty:

```
X = numpy.append(X, numpy.array(X[:,0],ndmin=2).T, axis=1)
```

In MATLAB one could just write: `X(:,361) = X(:,1)` !!!

I came to realize that this works, too:

```
X = numpy.insert(X, 361, X[:,0], axis=1)
```

but why append does not work similarly?

Thank you serpents

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that indexing with one integer removes that axis:

```
>>> X[:, 0].shape
(180,)
```

That's a one dimensional array, but if you index by giving a start and stop you keep the axis:

```
>>> X[:, 0:1].shape
(180, 1)
```

which could be correctly appended to your array:

```
>>> np.append(a, a[:, 0:1], 1)
array([....])
```

But all this aside if you find yourself `appending` and `concatenating` lots of arrays be warned: **These are extremly inefficient.** Most of the time it's better to find another way of doing this, for example creating a bigger array in the beginning and then just setting the rows/columns by slicing:

```
X = np.zeros((180, 361))
X[:, 360] = X[:, 0]  # much more efficient than appending or inserting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new axis on `X[:,0]`:

```
np.append(X, X[:,0,None], axis=1)
```

I think the reason why you have to match array shapes is that [`numpy.append`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L4523-L4575) is implemented using [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Answer (score 0):

A key difference is that in MATLAB everything has at least 2 dimensions.

```
>> size(x(:,1))
ans =
   2   1
```

and as you note, it allows indexing 'beyond-the-end' - way beyond

```
>> x(:,10)=x(:,1)
x =
   1   2   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
   4   5   6   4   0   0   0   0   0   4
```

But in `numpy` indexing reduces the dimensions, without the 2d floor:

```
In [1675]: x = np.ones((3,4),int)
In [1676]: x.shape
Out[1676]: (3, 4)
In [1677]: x[:,0].shape
Out[1677]: (3,)
```

That means that if I want to replicate a column I need to make sure it is still a column in the `concatenate`.  There are numerous ways of doing that.

`x[:,0][:,None]` - use of `np.newaxis` (alias `None`) is a nice general purpose method.  `x[:,[0]]`, `x[:,0:1]`, `x[:,0].reshape(-1,1)` also have their place.

`append` is just `concatenate` that replaces the list of arguments with 2.  It's a confusing imitation of the list append.  It is written Python so you can read it (as experienced MATLAB coders do).

`insert` is a more complicated function (also in Python).  Adding at the end it does something like:

```
In [1687]: x.shape
Out[1687]: (3, 4)
In [1688]: res=np.empty((3,5),int)
In [1689]: res[:,:4] = x
In [1690]: res[:,-1] = x[:,0]
```

That last assignment works because both sides have the same shape (technically they just have to be broadcastable shapes).  So `insert` doesn't tell us anything about what should or should not work in more basic operations like `concatenate`.